# How to access the moment object (from moment.js) from a QuickBase custom script

Tags: momentjs, getscript, quickbase

I've been writing a custom script for QuickBase, which requires some date manipulation. I decided to use moments.js and, since I'm using it within quickbase, I am loading moments.js dynamically, using $.getscript. I've done this process before with other plugin (jquery.md5.min.js), and this works correctly.

The problem is, even though moment.js is read correctly, when I try to use it (for instance, see the console.log() I added for debugging, I get an error message telling me that "moment is not defined".

I know moment.js is being read because I already had it dumped into the console after loading, and I'm trying to use its functions only after it is loaded via the asynchronous methods. I have also played with a few simple jsfiddles just to make sure I was calling it correctly. I also checked several times the url and it is correct. The rest of my code is also correct (if I comment out the lines with moment(), it works as expected).

```
$.getScript(domain + dbid_app + urlMoments)
  .done(function(script, textStatus) {
    rightNow = moment();
    dfd.resolve();  // Resolve when the script is finished loading.
    console.log("moments.js has finished loading.\n\n" + textStatus);
    console.log(rightNow);
  })
  .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
    console.log( "Triggered ajaxError handler." );
});
```

How do I call the moment() function? When running the fiddle, and after looking at many online examples, it is as simple as: `var myTime = moment();`, but this is not working inside of my script. Is there a chance that, even after loading moments.js with $.getscript(), it was not executed? From what I can see on the source code of moments.js, the factory function should be automatically called, shouldn't it?

```
(function (global, factory) {
typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? module.exports = factory() :
typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
global.moment = factory()
```

}

One last thing: the url points to the QuickBase code page I created with moments.js. This is also how I'm using jquery.md5.js without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your issue might be caused by Quickbase loading a different version of moment.js already.  Specifically, Quickbase forms are using [Moment 2.8.4](https://quickbase.intuitcdn.net/res/68801-18/js/moment.min.js) in some capacity and it is being loaded using [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).  Following Moment's example for using RequireJS I was able to get a moment object with the following code:

```
require(['moment'], function(){
    moment();
});

rightNow = moment();
```

I hope that helps you solve your problem.